# Bell polynomial with variables 1 and 0

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

Let $B_{n,k}(x_1,\cdots,x_{n-k+1})$ be the Bell polynomial.

If $x_1=\cdots=x_{n-k+1}=1$, we know that $B_{n,k}(x_1,\cdots,x_{n-k+1})=S(n,k)$, where $S(n,k)$ is the Stirling number of second kind.

Now, let $$y_i=\begin{cases}1,& i\leq r\\0,& r<i\leq n-k+1\end{cases} \text{,}$$ where $r$ is an integer number that $1\leq r<n-k+1$. Can we find a simple formula to express $G_r(n,k):= B_{n,k}(y_1,\cdots,y_{n-k+1})$ as the $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of Stirling numbers of second kind?

Theoretically, we can use the formula $$B_{n,k}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-k+1}\binom{n-1}{i-1}x_iB_{n-i,k-1}$$ recursively, but I wonder if there is a simpler choice. Or, at least, is there any consequence involving this $G_r(n,k)$?

---

The other question is that if $r$ is small enough, one has $G_r(n,k)=0$. Now let
$$H(n,k):=\max\{1\leq r<n-k+1\vert G_r(n,k)=0\} \text{,}$$
What can we say about $H(n,k)$? The trivial bound is $H(n,k)\geq \frac{n}{k}$.

Comment: Supposedly, you have found something nice for $r=n-k$ to begin with. May you share it?

Answer (score 2):

From the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Generating_function):
$$\sum_{n\geq k \geq 0} B_{n,k}(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-k+1}) \frac{t^n}{n!} u^k = \exp\left( u \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j \frac{t^j}{j!} \right)$$
it follows that
$$\sum_{n\geq k \geq 0} G_r(n,k) \frac{t^n}{n!} u^k = \exp\left( u \sum_{j=1}^r \frac{t^j}{j!} \right) = \prod_{j=1}^r \exp\left( u \frac{t^j}{j!} \right) ,$$
from where we can get an explicit formula:
$$G_r(n,k) = \sum_{i_1+\dots+i_r = k\atop i_1+2i_2+\dots+ri_r=n} \frac{n!}{1!^{i_1} 2!^{i_2} \cdots r!^{i_r}}.$$

It is also follows that $G_r(n,k)=0$ iff $kr<n$, that is $H(n,k) = \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{k}\right\rfloor$.